# Problem about complete metric spaces: proving that the Banach fixed-point theorem requires the map to be a contraction map

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that there exists a nonempty complete metric space $(X,d)$, and a function $f:X \rightarrow X$, such that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ whenever $ x \neq y$, and such that $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in X$.

I am thinking using Banach form to prove it is complete. Is this the correct way towards the proof?

It would be great if someone can show me how to prove this or at least explain how to prove.

Comment: *"let $f$ be in the metric space"* ???

Comment: Also, you are going to be **constructing** an example, not **proving** a general result.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, technically he/she could get away with an existence proof. (I agree, though, that exhibiting such $X,d,f$ is probably the way to go.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the example of $X=[1,\infty)$ and the map $f:X\to X$ defined by $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Clearly, we have $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in X$, and for any $x<y$, we have $$|f(y)-f(x)|=\lvert y-x+\tfrac{1}{y}-\tfrac{1}{x}\rvert<|y-x|$$ because
$$0<(y-x)<xy(y-x)\implies 0<(\tfrac{1}{x}-\tfrac{1}{y})<(y-x)\implies 0<(y-x+\tfrac{1}{y}-\tfrac{1}{x})<(y-x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it can be done with $X = \mathbb R$.  You just need a function $f$ such that $f(x) > x$ and $|f'(x)| < 1$